# Not able to create Tag in Google Tag Manager using the Google Tag Manager API

Tags: api, google-tag-manager

I want to use the Google Tag Manager API to programmatically create Tags in a containers workspace from a JSON file.

In doing so I encountered the following error after sending of a create-Request:

```
{
  "errors": {
      "error": {
         "errors": [
             {
               "domain": "global",
               "reason": "invalidArgument",
               "message": "Bad Request"
             }
          ],
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Bad Request"
   }  
}
```

I then tried to create a minimal tag in the same workspace following this example: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/devguide with the same result.

Its the same for another newly created container and workspace with no other elements in it.

Does someone know a possible solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to make sure, you have literally used the example code (else you'd need to include your code) ? Which language (exampmles are offered in python and JS)? IIRC You will also get a 400 response if an element with the same name already exists, so you can't run the code twice without changing the name of the tag.

Comment: @Johannes Roth, do you have any solutions?